# Updating to Spring Security 6.0 bring org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtFilter'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to upgrade to Spring Boot 3.0.0 and Spring Security 6.0.

when i learn my project i get this error :

***org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtFilter': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jwtUtility': Error creating bean with name 'jwtUtility': Injection of autowired dependencies failed***

My code in WebSecurityConfiguration file:

````
package com.ims.usermanagement.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.ims.usermanagement.jwt.JwtFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private JwtFilter jwtFilter;

  @Autowired
  private AuthEntryPointJwt unauthorizedHandler;

  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
      throws Exception {
    return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .requestMatchers("/authenticate/")
        .permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/utilisateur/photos/{id}")
        .permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/discussion/attachment/{id}")
        .permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/retrait/file/{id}/{name}")
        .permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/client/photos/{id}")
        .permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/partenaire/photos/{id}")
        .permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/resetPassword")
        .permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/resetPassword/reset")
        .permitAll()
        .requestMatchers("/autopayment/\\?token=.*$")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated();
    http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
  }

}```

thank you for your help
````

Comment: Maybe the anotation @ Component or @Bean is Missing in the class  JwtFilter  ?

Comment: Your filter can't be constructed because `jwtUtility` is not registered as a Bean in the Context. Can you show your filter and jwtUtility?